# Google App Engine - Issue authenticating deployed version of app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-bigquery

I built a simple python application to be run on the Google App Engine. Code:

```
import webapp2

from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('BigQuery App')
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
                                          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin')
    service = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    projectId = '<Project-ID>'

    query_request_body = {
        "query": "SELECT a from Data.test LIMIT 10"
    }

    request = service.jobs().query(projectId=projectId, body=query_request_body)
    response = request.execute()

    self.response.write(response)



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

I am able to deploy this code locally (http://localhost:8080) and everything works correctly, however I get the following error 500 Server Error when I try to deploy it to GAE using:

```
appcfg.py -A <Project-Id> -V v1 update .
```

This is the error I get from the Error Report Console:

```
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL:http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin/?recursive=True
```

I believe it is an auth issue and to make sure my service account was authorized I went through the gcloud authentification for service accounts and I also set the set environment variables from the SDK.

I have been trying to get around this for a while, any pointers are very appreciated. Thank you.

Also, I have been using Service Account Auth by following these docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount where it says that I shouldn't be able to run AppAsseritionCredenitals locally, which adds to my confusion because I actually can with no errors.

EDIT:

After reuploading and reauthorizing my service account I was able to connect to the server. However, the authorization error continues with this:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/sqlserver-1384/queries?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "error while connecting to the server", follow the  instructions listed in this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651973/default-credentials-in-google-app-engine-invalid-credentials-error#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651973/default-credentials-in-google-app-engine-invalid-credentials-error#_=_) 
and then re-upload the app

Then, to fix the HttpError 403 when requesting ... returned "Insufficient Permission", you have to change the scope you were requesting. In my case I was requesting:

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin')
```

however, the correct scope for Google BigQuery is:  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery. Which looks like this:

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
```

If you are using a different API, use whichever scope is outlined in the documentations.